# How to get image name from SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I would like to get name of the image which I use on SKSpriteNode.

This is how I create a node:

```
SKSpriteNode *button = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"img.png"];
```

By touching the screen I would like to get on NSLog the name of this image.

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint loc = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKSpriteNode *node = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:loc];
```

By touching node, I would like to get on NSLog information that this SKSpriteNode uses image named img.png.

How I should solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have direct access to the name of the image. A possible solution is to use the `name` property of the node for it.

```
NSString *filename = @"img.png";
SKSpriteNode *button = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:filename];
[button setName:filename];
```

That way you'd have name by simply printing the description of the object.

```
NSLog("Touched object %@", [node description]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this same question today and found an exact solution.  If you would like to access the image of your SKSpriteNode, try:

```
NSLog(@"Texture: %@",[button texture]);
```